# Merge array of alt tags in img array dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have an array of alt tags :

```
$array_alt=array("hii,
            "Best",
            "abc",
            //"board certified",
            "xyz",
            "hello",
            "new"
            )
```

Now What I want is to add these alt tags to ***img src dynamically***, i.e. for **image 1** ***alt*** tag should be **"hii"**, and same for the rest.

And this is how images are called dynamically through a folder and all the images appear in slider:

```
$images = scandir(images/all_images); // get path 
            sort($images,1); // 1 is to sort images numerically

            foreach($images as $img)
                { 
                    if($img === '.' || $img === '..')
                    {
                        continue;
                    }   
                    // check extensions as we need only images
                    if ((preg_match('/.jpg/',$img))  ||  (preg_match('/.gif/',$img)) || (preg_match('/.tiff/',$img)) || (preg_match('/.png/',$img)) )
                    {               
                        list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($path.$img);

                        if(($width<$height) || ($height>500) )
                        {
                        ?>
                            <div class="item img-landscape"><img class="lazyOwl" alt="" data-src="<?php echo $path.$img; ?>" ></div>
                           <?php
                        }
                        else{
                        ?>
                            <div class="item"><img class="lazyOwl" alt="" data-src="<?php echo $path.$img; ?>" ></div>
                           <?php
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
```

Please if any one could help me.

I tried using this, but nothing seems to work.

```
$images = scandir($img_path);
            sort($images,1); // 1 is to sort images numerically

            $i=0;
            foreach($images as $img)
                { 

                    echo $array_alt[$i]."<br>";
                    if($img === '.' || $img === '..')
                    {
                        continue;
                    }   
                    // check extensions as we need only images
                    if ((preg_match('/.jpg/',$img))  ||  (preg_match('/.gif/',$img)) || (preg_match('/.tiff/',$img)) || (preg_match('/.png/',$img)) )
                    {               
                        list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($path.$img);

                        if(($width<$height) || ($height>500) )
                        {
                        ?>
                            <div class="item img-landscape"><img class="lazyOwl" alt="<?php echo $array_alt[$i]?>" data-src="<?php echo $path.$img; ?>" ></div>
                           <?php
                        }
                        else{
                        ?>
                            <div class="item"><img class="lazyOwl" alt="<?php echo $array_alt[$i]?>" data-src="<?php echo $path.$img; ?>" ></div>
                           <?php
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                   $i++;  
                }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why the JavaScript and jQuery tags?

Comment: What error does you code display ? is your alt tag unchanged ? What is the problem ? A bit more information would be welcome :)

Comment: If this can be done using javascript or jquery, that's why thsee are also added

Comment: The code that I tried prints a same alt tag multiple time, which is of no use.
I want that each image should have its own alt tag as defined in the array

Comment: Are you sure that your matching rules are correct ? If you're saying that there is the same alt tag several times, the only way i could see why your code isn't working would be that your code would reach the continue; statement too often.

Comment: if I do not use the alt tags its working all correct, i.e. if I use title as the alt tag only it appears according to the requirement

Comment: since your comments indicate you've got things sorted, you should accept an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array_alt=array("hii",
        "Best",
        "abc",
        //"board certified",
        "xyz",
        "hello",
        "new"
        );

$img_path="images/slider";
$path=JURI::BASE().$img_path."/"; // url/path of the images
$images = scandir($img_path);
sort($images,1); // 1 is to sort images numerically

    $i=0;
    foreach($images as $img)
    { 
       if($img === '.' || $img === '..')
       {
           continue;
       }   
       // check extensions as we need only images
       if ((preg_match('/.jpg/',$img))  ||  (preg_match('/.gif/',$img)) || (preg_match('/.tiff/',$img)) || (preg_match('/.png/',$img)) )

                {               
                    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($path.$img);

                    if(($width<$height) || ($height>500) )
                    {
                    ?>
                        <div class="item img-landscape"><img class="lazyOwl" alt="<?php echo $array_alt[$i]?>" data-src="<?php echo $path.$img; ?>" ></div>
                       <?php
                    }
                    else{
                    ?>
                        <div class="item"><img class="lazyOwl" alt="<?php echo $array_alt[$i]?>" data-src="<?php echo $path.$img; ?>" ></div>
                       <?php
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
               $i++;  
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly your declaration is wrong..

```
$array_alt=array("hii,
        "Best",
        "abc",
        //"board certified",
        "xyz",
        "hello",
        "new"
        )
```

would be

```
$array_alt=array("hii",
        "Best",
        "abc",
        //"board certified",
        "xyz",
        "hello",
        "new"
        )
```

Comment: its the same, what's the difference

Comment: @user3480318 actually, it's not the same. You forgot to end the first string with a << " >> ("hii)

Comment: Yes, adding that solved my issue.
And my code worked

Answer (score 1):

Modified a bit your code (adding missing `"` after `"hii` in alts array, checking if key exists in `$array_alt`, simplifying extension check) and it seems to work for me :

```
<?php

$array_alt = array(
    "hii",
    "Best",
    "abc",
    "board certified",
    "xyz",
    "hello",
    "new"
);

$path = '/public_path/';
$images = scandir($img_path);
sort($images, SORT_NUMERIC); // SORT_NUMERIC == 1 is to sort images numerically

$allowedExtensions = array('jpg', 'gif', 'tiff', 'png');
$i = 0;
foreach ($images as $img) {
    if (isset($array_alt[$i])) {
        $alt = $array_alt[$i];
    } else {
        $alt = "default_alt_value";
    }
    echo $alt . "<br>";
    if ($img === '.' || $img === '..') {
        continue;
    }
// check extensions as we need only images
    if (!in_array(pathinfo($img, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $allowedExtensions)) {
        continue;
    }

    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($path . $img);

    if (($width < $height) || ($height > 500)) {
        ?>
        <div class="item img-landscape"><img class="lazyOwl" alt="<?php echo $alt ?>"
                                             data-src="<?php echo $path . $img; ?>"></div>
    <?php
    } else {
        ?>
        <div class="item"><img class="lazyOwl" alt="<?php echo $alt ?>"
                               data-src="<?php echo $path . $img; ?>"></div>
    <?php
    }
    $i++;
}
?>
```